# Why do I have 2 Bluetooth Icons on my panel?

Tags: indicator, panel, bluetooth

Im not sure I should be reporting this as a bug as it may have been something I have have done to cause this.  I have duplicate icons on my Panel for bluetooth and would like to remove them both.

```
Terminal Reading

 1074 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/sbin/bluetoothd
 5036 ?        Sl     0:02 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/blueman-applet
 5040 ?        Sl     0:00 bluetooth-applet
 5872 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto blue
```

I did a bit of exploring in Synaptic Package Manager but unfortunately, I'm none the wiser, however one is the blueman project the other is gnome.

Comment: Are they actually the same?  They may look the same, but what if you look at their menus (not just left-click, but try right click), particularly the "about"?  Ubuntu has several standard bluetooth management applets and you might be running more than one of them.

Comment: I maybe should have included the fact in the original questions that the menus are partially different therefore your assumption is correct. I looked at the Synaptic Package Manager to see if I could remove one of them but didnt find 2.  I will continue to investigate.

Comment: Hi Stephen.  In the terminal, type `ps ax | grep blue` and this will give you everything (and maybe a few more things) having to do with bluetooth running as processes on your system.  There should be two of them that have something like "applet" as part of their name.  If you're not sure, just paste in the whole thing in your answer and we can straighten it out.

Comment: @StephenMyall - blueman is not part of the default install - I would suggest you remove that package.

Comment: Glad to hear the problem has been resolved, Stephen. Fossfreedom -- doing so now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are they actually the same? They may look the same, but what if you look at their menus (not just left-click, but try right click), particularly the "about"? Ubuntu has several standard bluetooth management applets and you might be running more than one of them.

In the terminal, type `ps ax | grep blue` and this will give you everything (and maybe a few more things) having to do with bluetooth running as processes on your system. There should be two of them that have something like "applet" as part of their name. If you're not sure, just paste in the whole thing in your answer and we can straighten it out.

Ok, so as fossfreedom pointed out, blueman is not in the default Ubuntu install, so the fix is to just uninstall that.

Comment: I don't know whether I should create a new question or not. The default ubuntu/unity app indicator lacks of some features, such as sending to unpaired devices, so I would like to uninstall it instead of `blueman`. Which package should I uninstall to remove it?

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to solve the two-bluetooth-icons problem on the indicator is:

1. Open Ubuntu *Software Centre*,
2. Go to the *Installed* section,
3. Search for `Bluetooth`,
4. Remove the one except Blueman because it works best on 13.04.
5. Restart and you are done.

Answer (score 1):

Run this command to kill the blueman-applet ( ` is backquote )

```
kill -9 `ps axu | grep blueman | awk '{print $2}'`
```

Comment: Or just `pkill blueman-applet` (on 16.04)

Answer (score 0):

As of 2024 if you are having this problem with Gnome 45 / Ubuntu 23.10, it is likely [this bug](https://github.com/ubuntu/gnome-shell-extension-appindicator/issues/419) in gnome-shell-extension-appindicator. Reverting [this change](https://github.com/ubuntu/gnome-shell-extension-appindicator/commit/41a8e9c7ff20c0d45ff91a6329455e6f31f2e4aa) fixed it for me (as suggested in the bug report). I just did `locate statusNotifierWatcher.js` then edited the file to put that line back in, logged out, logged back in.