# Why do I have two bluetooth icons after the Ubuntu 14.04 upgrade?

Tags: icons, bluetooth, system-tray

Since I upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS ("Trusty Tahr") this afternoon, I now have two bluetooth icons shown in my system tray...

[image: Bluetooth icons in system tray (circled in yellow)]

Why do I have two bluetooth icons now shown, and how can I remove one of them?

---

This is not a duplicate of this:
 - [Why do I have 2 Bluetooth Icons on my panel?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/122396/why-do-i-have-2-bluetooth-icons-on-my-panel?rq=1)

In that question, the icons appear to be the same (mine are different, with VERY different options under each) and the poster wants to remove both... I want to identify the reason there are two, and remove just one of the icons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have blueman installed, try removing it from the software centre.

Comment: Worked a charm, thanks!

Just a note to anyone else with this problem, you will probably need to restart before the changes will take effect (I did)...